# How to set multiple scheduled loop? discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make an hourly announcement and will notify a role 5 minutes before the event starts. In the code that I have I set it using seconds, so I can test it. I'm using @tasks.loop, but after the first announcement the time is not synced anymore.

I also tried using 'while and datetime', it works, but it blocks all the commands that I have.

Here's the code for my task loop:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=55)
async def start():
    message_channel = client.get_channel(748017692505800774)
    t = dt.datetime.now()
    now = t.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')
    await message_channel.send(f'5 minutes until clock announcement. {now} <@&748048926032003164>')

@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
async def finish():
    message_channel = client.get_channel(748017692505800774)
    t = dt.datetime.now()
    now = t.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')
    await message_channel.send(f'The time now is **{now}** <@&748048926032003164>')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    start.start()
    finish.start()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `before_loop` so it will wait until the desired time and then it will start. then it will just loop based on the time in the definition `@tasks.loop(hours=2)`

Your tasks should look like this, call it by `timer.start()`

```py
@tasks.loop(hours=2)
async def timer():
    message_channel = client.get_channel(748017692505800774)
    t = dt.datetime.now()
    now = t.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')
    await message_channel.send(f'5 minutes until clock announcement. {now} <@&748048926032003164>')
    await asyncio.sleep(5 * 60)  # wait 5 min and send again
    await message_channel.send(f'The time now is **{now}** <@&748048926032003164>')


@timer.before_loop
async def before_timer():
    for _ in range(60):# it will loop wait until sec is zero
        t = dt.datetime.now()
        now = t.strftime('%S')
        if now == '00':
            break

        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```